how can i use becautifulsoup find this element
I am trying to catch the date on the website, but the result is [].
Below is my code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
content = requests.get("https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/Results.aspx?lang=ch")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, "html.parser")
run_date = soup.find_all("div.resultMainRow")
print(run_date)

try to catch the date and number in recent 20 time


requests + BeautifulSoup won't work, because your data is loaded dynamically. Often that means you need something like selenium (cf. e.g. here). But you're in luck, as your data is fetched from a particular API endpoint:
https://bet.hkjc.com/contentserver/jcbw/cmc/last30draw.json

On how to locate such a (potential) endpoint, see e.g. here.
Normally, we could access this as follows:
import requests
import json

url = "https://bet.hkjc.com/contentserver/jcbw/cmc/last30draw.json"

resp = requests.get(url)

data = resp.json()

However, in this case, we will get an error on the last line:
JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)

The issue here is that the actual encoding is utf-8-sig, even though resp has it set to utf-8:
print(resp.encoding)
'utf-8'

Overwrite the value and all is well:
resp = requests.get(url)

resp.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'

data = resp.json()

data now contains a list of dicts like this:
data[0] # truncating the print

{'id': '24/064',
 'date': '04/06/2024',
 ...
 'p7': '40',
 'p7u': '69,982.2'}

Finally, to work with date and no values from each dict, you could collect them in two lists:
date, no = ([d[k] for d in data] for k in ("date", "no"))

Output:
print(date[:2])
['04/06/2024', '01/06/2024']

print(no[:2])
['6+11+19+21+27+43', '6+18+28+33+36+48']

Or if you prefer, you could for instance create a pd.DataFrame:
import pandas as pd

# specifying `columns` limit the keys loaded from the `dicts`
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'no'])

df.head()

         date                 no
0  04/06/2024   6+11+19+21+27+43
1  01/06/2024   6+18+28+33+36+48
2  30/05/2024   1+24+25+27+30+32
3  28/05/2024  33+37+38+43+44+46
4  25/05/2024   7+26+30+37+46+49

